# .htacess no funciona en servidor linux

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, apache2, debian

Tengo un fichero .htaccess dentro de mi proyecto php que la configuración de mi máquina local si que funciona (Windows + apache), aquí funcionan las urls del tipo "/talleres/barcelona/" o "/talleres/zaragoza"

El contenido del htaccess es este

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?mod=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1

RewriteRule ^talleres/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?mod=talleres&op=$1
```

El problema lo tengo cuando despliego este código en un servidor remoto, dicha máquina es un debian con **nginx** y **apache2**.

Comment: Y vas a usar el nginx o apache? Y cuál de tus etiquetas es la correcta, apache o apache2?

Comment: En local uso apache2 pero en producción uso nginx

Comment: Para la próxima, indica eso en la pregunta. No es nada evidente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he corregido con esta web que permite convertir entre .htaccess de apache y nginx.

EL resultado ha sido este

```
# nginx configuration by winginx.com

location / {
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?mod=$1;
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /index.php?mod=$1;
}

location /talleres {
   rewrite ^/talleres/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /index.php?mod=talleres&op=$1;
```

}